# Edit a piece of data inside a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file looking like this

```
34512340,1
12395675,30
56756777,30
90673412,45
12568673,25
22593672,25
```

I want to be able to edit the data after the comma from python and then save the csv.

Does anybody know how I would be able to do this?
This bit of code below will write a new line, but not edit:

```
f = open("stockcontrol","a")
f.write(code)
```

Comment: use the standard [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. it allows to parse the data into standard python lists and the to serialize data back to csv

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, which adds 1 to the second column:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as infile, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        # Transform the second column, which is row[1]
        row[1] = int(row[1]) + 1
        writer.writerow(row)
```

## Notes

- The `csv` module correctly parses the CSV file--highly recommended
- By default, each row will be parsed as text, what is why I converted into integer: `int(row[1])`

## Update

If you really want to edit the file "in place", then use the `fileinput` module:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('data.csv', inplace=True):
    fields = line.strip().split(',')
    fields[1] = str(int(fields[1]) + 1)  # "Update" second column
    line = ','.join(fields)
    print line  # Write the line back to the file, in place
```

Comment: I need to update the values in the file - not make a new one with the new values.

Comment: As I said, this is a sample. Also, I cannot guess what you meant by **update**. If you need specific answer, please provide specific question. As for new file vs. old. You can always delete the old file and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `pandas` to edit the column you want for e.g increase the column number by `n`:

```
import pandas
data_df = pandas.read_csv('input.csv')
data_df = data_df['column2'].apply(lambda x: x+n)
print data_df
```

for adding `1` replace `n` by `1`.

Comment: 'ImportError: No module named 'pandas''

Comment: Install `pandas` using `1) sudo apt-get install python-pip
2) sudo pip install numpy
3) sudo pip install pandas